# Numpy - group data into sum values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, set, grouping

Say I have an array of values:

```
a = np.array([1,5,4,2,4,3,1,2,4])
```

and three 'sum' values:

```
b = 10
c = 9
d = 7
```

Is there a way to group the values in `a` into groups of sets where the values combine to equal b,c and d? For example:

```
b: [5,2,3]
c: [4,4,1]
d: [4,2,1]

b: [5,4,1]
c: [2,4,3]
d: [4,2,1]

b: [4,2,4]
c: [5,4]
d: [1,1,2,3]
```

Note the sum of `b`,`c` and `d` should remain the same (==26). Perhaps this operation already has a name?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to solve the "knapsack problem" (or a variant thereof): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: Similar yes, I'd call it the "multiple knapsack problem". E.g. How many ways can you pack your stuff into three knapsacks (where cost isn't an issue).

Comment: So it is a search problem, not a numeric (numpy) one.  And as with most search problems, there is a brute force solution, and various strategies (often heuristic) for pruning off deadend branches.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a naive implementation using itertools

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def group(n, iterable):
    s = list(iterable)
    return [c for c in chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r)
                                           for r in range(len(s)+1))
            if sum(c) == n]
```

---

```
group(5, range(5))
```

yields

```
[(1, 4), (2, 3), (0, 1, 4), (0, 2, 3)]
```

Note, this probably will be very slow for large lists because we're essentially constructing and filtering through the power set of that list.

---

You could use this for

```
sum_vals = [10, 9, 7]
a = [1, 5, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 2, 4]

map(lambda x: group(x, a), sum_vals)
```

and then `zip` them together.

Comment: This does not satisfy the implicit condition that each value in `a` can only be placed into one group.

Comment: @askewchan, you are right. But I think it could be a good starting point. I've been toying with using `np.unique(group(b,a))` and then somehow pruning after testing with outputs from `group(c,a)` and `group(d,a)`. Haven't succeeded yet though.

Comment: Yes, all it lacks is a filter at the end that checks that the two collections are equal.  `np.unique` isn't sufficient because while order doesn't matter, the count of each entry does.  You could compare their `bincount`s.

Comment: This should work: `filter(lambda row: np.all(np.bincount(np.concatenate(row)) == np.bincount(a)), zip(*map(lambda x: group(x, a), sum_vals)))`

Comment: But actually, your original output is incomplete as well.  It doesn't have the second or third output that @atomh33ls found, but it did find a new one that @atomh33ls didn't find: `((4, 2, 4), (5, 3, 1), (1, 2, 4))`